# Call Node.js (or python) from Perl

Tags: python, node.js, perl

I have a legacy system written in Perl that I'd like to start migrating away from to something more modern. Python is my personal preference, but the team is very JS oriented.

I'd like to migrate various perl modules to node or python as step one of the process. Prior research includes googling (all results in opposite direction) and stack overflow (nothing relevant). I am aware of [backticks](http://www.perlhowto.com/executing_external_commands) but was wondering if there's anything more structured like JNI or if someone has some alternative and more elegant solution.

Comment: You can run both Python as well as JavaScript inside of Perl, as part of the Perl program. That might not be the fastest, but could work. Otherwise, you'll need to define clear interfaces and make different programs talk to each other. This is however a bit broad for Stack Overflow. You might get a good answer on programmers.se if you rephrase the question to something along the lines of "what strategy can I employ to port an application from language 1 to language 2 step by step while keeping it in production" and then go into details.

Comment: Oh btw, why do you consider Perl not modern? :P

Comment: I admit my judgement of 'modern' is very subjective. Perl has fallen from favour a few years ago and I found it to be very 'beginner unfriendly'. I also don't like the lack of function prototypes. Mostly, people today don't use it, so new team members have to learn it or be recruited for it (which is harder than for python/node).

Comment: Writing inline was what I was looking for. There's an answer for python but how does one write node inline?

Comment: I agree with the part about recruiting and finding developers. I don't think it's beginner unfriendly though, we merely suck at marketing it big time. :) But this will quickly go very off-topic, so I say we don't discuss this here. I meant that comment more as a jest. ;)

Comment: Well there's https://metacpan.org/pod/JavaScript.

Comment: Or with a Perl6 VM. But that is going to be very experimental. And inlining will not be the most performant thing anyway. Do you want to do this in a step-by-step way where every step gets released to production? Will there also be developers working on new features on the same product at the same time? Or are you fine with a complete rewrite and replacement when it's done? How big is the project?

Comment: There is also https://www.npmjs.com/package/perl, which seems to be the other way around, though I highly doubt this is really inlined.

Comment: It's a very large project and beyond my grokking. I'm currently touching one small part of it and exploring an idea of  making that relevant part accessible to others without the pain I went through. Other strategies such as Perl6 or full porting are no go. It needs to be limited in scope and time.

Comment: Perl now has what I assume you mean by [function prototypes](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2015/04/use-v5-20-subroutine-signatures/).

Comment: If it's like that then maybe it would be a better idea to rip that part out completely, reimplement it in a technology the team will feel more comfortable using, and then sticking that in through an API. For the last part you of course need to write some kind of client for that API in Perl, but that seems to be the least problematic approach. All those inlining things are nice for playing around, but I am not so sure I would want to use that in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Python, I'd recommed inline-python module from CPAN:
http://search.cpan.org/dist/Inline-Python/Python.pod

Example:

```
   use Inline Python => <<END;

   def Foo():
       class Bar:
           def __init__(self):
               print "new Bar()"
           def tank(self):
               return 10
       return Bar()

   END

   my $o = Foo();
   print $o->tank(), "\n";
```